Frame Rate Drop Issue in NIR Camera Streaming Using C++ OpenCV with GStreamer
Currently, I am developing and testing a program that outputs real-time images from an NIR camera in an ARM64 processor environment running Ubuntu 20.04 OS, using C++ OpenCV 4.5.4 library. When using the GStreamer command in the terminal, I get 30fps, but when reading the camera feed using the OpenCV VideoCapture function, I only get 13fps, which is causing an issue. I need advice on how this resolve problem
GStremaer Command
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080,fornats=YUY2 ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink drop=2

C++ OpenCV Code
int main()
{
    int vcNum = 0;                
    const int WAIT = 1;
    const char* gst_l = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1, formats=NV16 ! appsink drop=true, sync=false";
    cv::VideoCapture cap_ir(gst_l, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);

    if(!cap_ir.isOpened())
    {
        std::cerr << "Please check the camera port" << std::endl;

        return -1;
    }
    cap_ir.set(cv::CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 3);



    while (true)
    {
        cv::Mat mat_ir;

        cap_ir >> mat_ir;
        if (mat_ir.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "[INFO] frame is empty" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        
        // cv::resize(mat_ir, mat_ir, cv::Size(640, 360), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
        // cv::imshow("mat_ir", mat_ir);

        if (cv::waitKey(WAIT) > -1)
        {
            cv::destroyAllWindows();
            cap_ir.release();
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

Is there any way to improve it? I don’t know why my FPS is dropping

Can you remove the resize and the imshow and just count the received franes? Move the cv::Mat mat_ir; out of the loop.

I initially tried resizing and using imshow as you suggested. However, when I displayed the image without resizing, the FPS dropped even more since the image was 1920 x 1080. After resizing and then using imshow, the FPS was around 13. Although I removed the code that estimates FPS when I posted the code, in reality, when I use the FPS measurement code, it shows around 13 FPS

I meant to remove the displaying completely.

Unlike the example code posted earlier, the actual code being used doesn't include FPS measurement or the cv::imshow function to display the video on the screen. Additionally, there's no resizing happening, and even in this situation, the program runs at only 14fps. As far as I know, the NIR camera currently being used is connected to the board via a 4-pin connector rather than USB.

Interestingly, when I run it directly in the terminal with GStreamer, the output is consistently at 30fps. However, when reading images through OpenCV in the C++ code, there's a noticeable slowdown. I would like to understand the cause of this issue and the solution. I’m seeking advice on how to resolve this.

There are 2 direct differences: 1. you convert once to YUV and the other time to NV16. 2. you are displaying the images in opencv case. Can you remove the imshow? It is slow. And can you try NV16 format in the command line version? Also check the the configured fps with the Getter of the VideoCapture element.

Also there is an additional ! videoconvert ! in your opencv variant which is not there in the command line variant

besides that, OpenCV might add another conversion step, which is from whatever source format, to BGR. that is OpenCV's preferred representation and also required by imshow and imwrite
